# Mysql optimize index overhead for MIN, MAX and SUM

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize my table and my query and I didn't found any solution.

Table size: 2246096 rows

Query:

```
SELECT
    MIN(id) AS first_id,
    MAX(id) AS last_id,
    column_1,
    column_2,
    column_3,
    SUM(column_4 + column_5) AS total_4_5,
    SUM(column_6 + column_7) AS total_6_7,
    SUM(column_8 + column_9) AS total_8_9,
    SUM(column_10 + column_11) AS total_10_11
FROM table WHERE
    created_at BETWEEN '2021-10-01 07:45:00' and '2021-11-01 07:44:59'
    OR `id` IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7...)
GROUP BY
    column_1, column_2;
```

Using a single index on all columns the query is running well but my overhead is very big.

| Data | 2.9 | GiB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Index | 6.3 | GiB |
| Overhead | 514.0 | MiB |
| Effective | 8.7 | GiB |
| Total | 9.2 | GiB |

Is there any other way to get min, max, columns and sum without adding an index with all columns?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: "only_full_group_by" -- Shouldn't you include `column_3` in the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Are you sure about the `OR`?  The WHERE clause does not make much sense.  Please describe it in different words.

Comment: We can remove the OR clause...but from what I tested or id IN works very fast. I presented you the full query but also without OR condition the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases `OR` defeats optimization.  Normally I suggest using `UNION` as a performance workaround.  But, because of the `SUMs`, that is hard to do.

```
created_at BETWEEN '2021-10-01 07:45:00' and '2021-11-01 07:44:59'
OR `id` IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7...)

( SELECT ...
    WHERE created_at >= '2021-10-01 07:45:00'
      AND created_at  < '2021-10-01 07:45:00' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ...
    WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7...)
      AND NOT (
                created_at >= '2021-10-01 07:45:00'
            AND created_at  < '2021-10-01 07:45:00' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY ... )
```

Indexes needed:

```
PRIMARY KEY(id)  -- I assume you have this
INDEX(created_at)
```

Comment: as I said above, the OR condition is not my issue. I'm not able to improve the time if I don't add all the columns from select in the main index.